# Painting in buffer. Issue with alpha chanel

Tags: opengl, buffer, blending, fbo

I try to implement something like a paint tool and stuck with a problem alpha chanel of brush. My brush is a .PNG texture with transparent background. I draw in the RGBA buffer. My code:

```
initFBO(...)
...

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FBO);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

drawBrush(...)

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0); 

drawFBO(...)
```

It works but if I stop my brush, alpha channel from brush will be to accumulate in the buffer to replace color from.

[image]

I'm not familiar with blending in Opengl too close and have issue with blending parameters. Is my problem in the blending or something else?

**Update:**

```
initFBO(GLuint &framebuff, GLuint &text)
{
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuff);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuff);
    glGenTextures(1, &text);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, text);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, screenWidth, screenHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, text, 0);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

drawBrush(glm::vec2 mousePosition, GLuint texture, Shader shader)
{
    glm::mat4 model;
    model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(mousePosition, 1.0));

    GLfloat brushVertices[] =
    {
        -0.1f, 0.1f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.1f,-0.1f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
         0.1f, 0.1f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.1f,-0.1f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
    };

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &brushVAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &brushVBO);
    glBindVertexArray(brushVAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, brushVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(brushVertices), &brushVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    shader.set();
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "texture"), 0);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "model"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glBindVertexArray(brushVAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

drawFBO(GLuint texture, Shader shader)
{
    GLfloat screenquadVertices[] =
    {
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f,0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f
    };

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &screenquadVAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &screenquadVBO);
    glBindVertexArray(screenquadVAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, screenquadVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(screenquadVertices), &screenquadVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    shader.set();
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "texture"), 0);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glBindVertexArray(screenquadVAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

**Update2**

Ok. I tried both your recomend but results are simmilar and don't explain my problem. Look at:

1) `glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);` and two premultiplied .PNG texture - witha black and with white.

[image]

2) `glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);` and straight-alpha texture.

[image]

Comment: Is depth test disabled?

Comment: Yes. If i enable it nothing changes.

Comment: The image you posted -- it's an image of what? What is the 'Draw FBO' code, 'Draw brush' code, and how did you set up your FBO?

Comment: Ok, I update it. Image what i get when trying to draw in opengl window. When I stop the brush it start slow "burning" what I painted before, if you understand me.

Comment: @OpenGLNoob: nope, I don't. Don't you clear the buffers? It's hard to tell from your code because it's just incoherent pieces. Please post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the future. As for now I suspect that the problem is that you render to a transparent texture that's not a premultiplied alpha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When blending into a texture with a straight alpha channel, the correct blending equations involve a division by the alpha values, and such equations cannot be expressed within the linear formulas that OpenGL (and GPUs) provide with the `glBlendFunc` and `glBlendFuncSeparate`.

Instead, you should use premultiplied alpha. In principle you do that by calling

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

once, and ensuring that all your inputs and outputs are premultiplied alpha.

However, standard PNGs are in straight alpha (though non-standard PNGs with premultiplied alpha exist... probably not your case). To deal with it you can either premultiply the PNGs when you load them, or use the following when in `drawBrush`:

```
glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

That will get a straight alpha shader output and blend it into a premultiplied alpha framebuffer. Therefore, when rendering that framebuffer to the screen, remember to use the `glBlendFunc` for premultiplied alpha (the first one).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will keep in mind how it influence on render result in future. I tried your solution and other combinations with and w/o premultiplying (look update), but seems to me problem lies elsewhere. My framebuffer accumulate not only color but and alpha value in game loop and it influence on FBO. When I stop a brush it start bleeding as ink on a paper. Now I try to figure out how to solve it but I can't.((

Comment: @OpenGLNoob: do you realize that you posted no mouse-related code, and therefore we cannot help with that part? Please learn to post a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes, you are right. My mistake was I didn't control update my FBO by mouse movement  and placed painting pipeline into the game loop directly. FBO was accumulating alpha every frame and it was the reason of my problem. Thank you!